# $H_0=\{f\in C[0,1] \mid f(0)=f(1)=0, f' \text{ piecewise continuous}\}$ and supremum norm

Tags: real-analysis, hilbert-spaces

For $f\in H_0$ if we define $\langle f,g\rangle_{H_0}=\int^1_0f'(x)g'(x)dx$, and assume $f'\in L^2[0,1]$, how do we show that $f$ is continuous and $\lVert f \rVert_{C[0,1]} \leq \lVert f \rVert_{H_0}$?

Comment: I'm confused. By $C[0, 1]$, do you mean the space of continuous functions under the supremum norm? If so, then how do we guarantee the existence of the derivatives for the inner product?

Comment: Right derivative I believe, fixed. Yet even in this scenario this part is still confusing to me too, seems like f being continuous is like given.

Comment: It's more than that. Consider the sequence of functions $f_n(x) = \sin(2\pi n x)$. Then $\|f_n\|_{H_0} \rightarrow \infty$, but $\|f_n\|_\infty = 1$. The inequality can't hold.

Comment: The inequality holds for this case right? $H_0$ is the larger one. I can't prove it, tried those obvious ways, like Schwarz, Holder, bounding integrand by its maximum...

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry about that. I'll have another think.

Comment: What about $f(x)$, defined as a piecewise linear function, connecting the points $(0, 0)$, $(1/2,1/10)$ and $(1, 0)$? Then the $H_0$ norm is $1/25$ and the $\infty$ norm is $1/10$. (It's late, so I may be off on my calculations.)

Comment: Well you missed the square root for $H_0$ norm as a $L^2$ norm I suppose, so should be $1/5$. My naive idea is that piecewise linear function should be the worst case scenario. If this holds then everything will hold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I got it! Sorry about the litany of mistakes. For $0 \le x \le 1$, by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality and the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus,
$$f(x)^2 = \left(\int_0^x f'(t) \mathrm{d}t\right)^2 \le \int_0^x f'(t)^2 \mathrm{d}t \int_0^x 1\mathrm{d}t = x\int_0^x f'(t)^2 \mathrm{d}t \le \int_0^1 f'(t)^2 \mathrm{d}t.$$
Taking the supremum over $x$ and square roots of both sides yields the result.